# @Asynchronous annotation not working

Tags: amazon-swf

I have three groups. The first two groups can execute in parallel. The third group can execute only after the successful execution of first and second group. Problem is that all of them are executing randomly. There is no orchestration as such.

```java
public class AsyncWorkflowImpl implements AsyncWorkflow{

    private AsyncActivitiesClient activitiesClient = new AsyncActivitiesClientImpl();
    private Async2ActivitiesClient activitiesClient2 = new Async2ActivitiesClientImpl();
    @Override
    public void executeActivity() {

        Promise<Integer> intermediateRes = null;
        Promise<Integer> intermediateRes2 = null;
        Settable<Integer> finalRes = new Settable<Integer>();
        Settable<Integer> finalRes2 = new Settable<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            intermediateRes = testIntermediate(Promise.asPromise(i), intermediateRes);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            intermediateRes2 = testIntermediate2(Promise.asPromise(i), intermediateRes2);
        }
        finalRes.chain(intermediateRes);
        finalRes2.chain(intermediateRes2);
        List<Promise<Integer>> promiseList = new ArrayList<Promise<Integer>>();
        promiseList.add(finalRes);
        promiseList.add(finalRes2);
        test(promiseList);
    }
    @Asynchronous
    public Promise<Integer> testIntermediate(Promise<Integer> i, Promise<Integer> res){

        return activitiesClient.testAct1(i);
    }
    @Asynchronous
    public Promise<Integer> testIntermediate2(Promise<Integer> i, Promise<Integer> res){

        return activitiesClient2.testAct1(i);
    }
    @Asynchronous
    public void test(@Wait List<Promise<Integer>> promiseList){

        activitiesClient.testAct2();
    }
}
```

**package: com.myco.test**

**src/main/resources/aop.xml**

```xml
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <!-- declare two existing aspects to the weaver -->
        <aspect name="com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.aspectj.AsynchronousAspect"/>
        <aspect name="com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.aspectj.ExponentialRetryAspect"/>
    </aspects>
    <weaver options="-verbose">
        <include within="com.myco.test..*"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </source>
                    <source>
                        <basedir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</basedir>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </source>
                </sources>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Default VM arguement:**

-javaagent:C:\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjweaver.jar

Comment: possible duplicate of [DecisionTaskTimedOut when @Asynchronous annotation is used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602298/decisiontasktimedout-when-asynchronous-annotation-is-used)

Comment: This is the same code and the same solution with the duplicate listed above me.