# DecisionTaskTimedOut when @Asynchronous annotation is used

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have some two sets of activity that needs to be executed in parallel. After their successful completion, I want to execute another set of activity. I used Task and it was working. But, after using the @Asynchronous annotation, I am getting the DecisionTaskTimedOut and none of the activity starts its execution. My aspectj configuration is working as i can see the following classes in my target:

AsyncWorkflowImpl$AjcClosure1.class

AsyncWorkflowImpl$AjcClosure3.class

AsyncWorkflowImpl$AjcClosure5.class

**Asynchronous Version**

```
 public class AsyncWorkflowImpl implements AsyncWorkflow{

        private AsyncActivitiesClient activitiesClient = new AsyncActivitiesClientImpl();
        private Async2ActivitiesClient activitiesClient2 = new Async2ActivitiesClientImpl();

        @Override
        public void executeActivity() {

            Promise<Integer> intermediateRes = null;
            Promise<Integer> intermediateRes2 = null;
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                intermediateRes = testIntermediate(Promise.asPromise(i), intermediateRes);
            }
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                intermediateRes2 = testIntermediate2(Promise.asPromise(i), intermediateRes2);
            }
            test(intermediateRes,intermediateRes2);
        }

        @Asynchronous
        public Promise<Integer> testIntermediate(final Promise<Integer> i, Promise<Integer> res){

            return  activitiesClient.testAct1(i); 
        }

        @Asynchronous
        public Promise<Integer> testIntermediate2(final Promise<Integer> i, Promise<Integer> res){
            return  activitiesClient2.testAct1(i); 
        }

        @Asynchronous
        public void test(final Promise<Integer> res, final Promise<Integer> res2){

            activitiesClient.testAct2();
        }

    }
```

**Task Version**

```java
public class AsyncWorkflowImpl implements AsyncWorkflow{

    private AsyncActivitiesClient activitiesClient = new AsyncActivitiesClientImpl();
    private Async2ActivitiesClient activitiesClient2 = new Async2ActivitiesClientImpl();

    @Override
    public void executeActivity() {

        Promise<Integer> intermediateRes = null;
        Promise<Integer> intermediateRes2 = null;
        Settable<Integer> finalRes = new Settable<Integer>();
        Settable<Integer> finalRes2 = new Settable<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            intermediateRes = testIntermediate(i, intermediateRes);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            intermediateRes2 = testIntermediate2(i, intermediateRes2);
        }
        finalRes.chain(intermediateRes);
        finalRes2.chain(intermediateRes2);
        test(finalRes,finalRes2);
    }

    public Promise<Integer> testIntermediate(final Integer i, Promise<Integer> res){
        final Settable<Integer> tempRes = new Settable<Integer>();
        new Task(res){
            @Override
            protected void doExecute() throws Throwable {

                tempRes.chain(activitiesClient.testAct1(i)); 
            }
        };
        return tempRes;
    }

    public Promise<Integer> testIntermediate2(final Integer i, Promise<Integer> res){
        final Settable<Integer> tempRes = new Settable<Integer>();
        new Task(res){
            @Override
            protected void doExecute() throws Throwable {

                tempRes.chain(activitiesClient2.testAct1(i)); 
            }
        };
        return tempRes;
    }

    public void test(final Promise<Integer> res, final Promise<Integer> res2){

        new Task(res, res2){
            @Override
            protected void doExecute() throws Throwable {

                activitiesClient.testAct2();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Is there any problem in aspectj weaving? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

An [@Asynchronous](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/annotations/Asynchronous.html) method is executed when **all** of its parameters that extend type Promise are ready. Your @Asynchronous methods are never executed because of the *res* parameter which is never ready. The solution is to annotate such parameters with [@NoWait](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/annotations/NoWait.html) to inform the framework that these should not be waited.

The best way to troubleshoot workflows that appears "stuck" is by looking at their "asynchronous stack trace" that contains async stack traces of all outstanding tasks. Use [WorkflowExecutionFlowThreadDumper](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/common/WorkflowExecutionFlowThreadDumper.java) to emit such a trace.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Promise as null isn't in ready? I want to execute the testIntermediate method sequentially and testIntermedaite2 method sequetially. If i use @NoWait annotation then will it wait for the completion of previous one?

Comment: You can replace null with Promise.asPromise(0) to see if it is indeed an issue.